# Variable always returns the word "Null"

Tags: php, null, echo

The following code executes query1 if the 'Less than 16' checkbox is checked and executes query2 if the '16 or more' checkbox is checked. This works perfectly.

```
<?php
//error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','student','student') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('vgs',$conn);

//Get Question 1
if (isset($_GET['q1option'])) 
{
    $q1option = $_GET['q1option'];
} 
else 
{
    $q1option = "Null";
}

echo("".$_GET['q1option']);
echo("".$q1option);

//Process Question 1
if ($q1option == "Less than 16") 
{
    $query1 = "UPDATE free_hours SET times_selected=times_selected+1 WHERE q1option='Less than 16'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
if ($q1option == "16 or more") 
{
    $query2 = "UPDATE free_hours SET times_selected=times_selected+1 WHERE q1option='16 or more'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

However, I get the following error when I echo $_GET['q1option'].

"Notice: Undefined index: q1option in C:\wamp\www\Student\vgs\process_answers.php on line 16"

Line 16 is this:

```
echo("".$_GET['q1option']);
```

Also, when I echo $q1option it always echos the word "Null" even if Less than 16 is checked and the 'times_selected' value is incrementing.

What is the problem here?

Thanks for any help.

Daniel

Comment: Could you show your HTML of the form that calls this?

Comment: You really shouldn't make NULL as string as you do here `$q1option = "Null";` See this for what NULL is: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

Comment: `<form id="vgsForm" action="process_answers.php" method="get" >
<div id="Q1">
<label><input type="radio" name="q1option" value="Less than 16" />Less than 16</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="q1option" value="16 or more" />16 or more</label>`

Comment: Is that you that wrote that code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not receiving a `GET` parameter called `q1option`.  Check your client-side code with debugger and make sure it's being sent.

You can see what you are receiving server-side by doing something like:

```
error_log('$_GET: '.print_r($_GET, true));
```

(alternatively you can echo it out if you're in a safe environment).

Comment: At the top of your PHP file.

Comment: I did that and nothing changed. I posted the relevant form code in a comment above, if that helps.

Comment: i echoed it and this appeared: $_GET: Array ( )

Comment: Should it be echoing:    $_GET: q1option    ?

Comment: Right, `Array()` is telling you that the are no `GET` parameters being received from your client-side code. So focus on your HTML.  Also, it's standard StackOverflow practice to up-vote any answers you find to be helpful.

Comment: I cannot up-vote as it says I need 15 reputation first. I'm really sorry but I appreciate the help. Can you have a look at the HTML form above? The following is JavaScript code embedded in the HTML. It uses JQuery.

`$(document).ready(function()
{
 // bind 'vgsForm' and provide a simple callback function 
 $('#vgsForm').ajaxForm(function()
 {
  $('#Suggestion').load('process_answers.php');
 }); 
});`

Answer (score 0):

first:
wrap

```
echo("".$_GET['q1option']);
```

into

```
    if(isset($_GET['q1option'])){
      echo("".$_GET['q1option']);
    }
```

to get rid of notice, then
if your $_GET doesn't hold a thing, make sure you use  or  to submit your form, and you don't accidentally trying to put two forms and submit another one ;). Whole code (form file + process_answers.php) would help here, that's for sure.